# "With" use in a (implicit) nested loop

Tags: scoping, procedural-programming

Symbolic code:

`Do[g[longcat[i,k],longcat[i,k]],{i,1,f[k]},{k,1,m}]`

Longcat is loooong and occurs several times in my expression `g`. Obviously I'd like to replace any instance by `With[{long=longcat[i,k]},Do[g[long,long],...]]` but the second loop gets in the way. Where does the `With` belong (maybe I have to split my single `Do` into two explicit ones and it's not possible this way with a single)?

EDIT: My code is now (working modulo possible on-off bugs, the Ceilings may be kaput; the square of p shall be the unit matrix in any case):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
t={t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9,t10}; (* around Total[P]/2 elements *)
P={4,5,7,1};
n=Total[P];
p=ConstantArray[0,{n,n}];
Do[With[{S1=1+Sum[P[[m]],{m,1,k-1}],S2=Sum[P[[m]],{m,1,k}]},Do[p[[i,S1+S2-i]]=Which[i<=(S1+S2-1)/2,t[[i+1-Ceiling[(S1+1)/2]]],i>=(S1+S2+1)/2,1/t[[Ceiling[S1/2]+S2-i]],True,1],{i,S1,S2}]],{k,1,Length[P]}];
```

As you see, I have split the Do loops and made a Do-With-Do structure, since my Longcats depend on the outer loop. Does this work with a single Do?

Comment: It would go inside the loop if you wanted to avoid computing it twice, like: `Do[With[{long = longcat[i, k]}, g[long, long]], {i, 1, f[k]}, {k, 1, m}]`

Comment: @flinty: You can make that an answer (I'm still testing :-), my issue was mainly where the closing bracket of With belongs, where you put it - or after one of the closing curly brackets.

Comment: If you have functions that take long to evaluate but return outputs that don't consume too much memory, you might want to consider memoisation. See also this [resource function](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/WithCachedValues).